# Query for Number of Active Subscribers and Subscriptions in Past Year (By Day)

Tags: sql, date, plsql

I am seeking to write a query that allows me to capture the number of active subscribers and subscriptions in the past year (By day). For example, the below query will tell us the number of unique subscribers and subscriptions that were actively subscribed anytime between June 2, 2013 and June 1, 2014.

```
SELECT      count(distinct(user_id)) as subscribers, 
            count(distinct(subscription_id)) as subscriptions
FROM        dataset
WHERE       (start_date <= to_date('01JUN2014:23:59:59','DDMONYYYY:HH24:MI:SS') and 
            end_date >= to_date('02JUN2013:00:00:00','DDMONYYYY:HH24:MI:SS')) and
            payment_amt > 0;
```

With that being said, I am seeking a query that allows me to simultaneously capture all active subscribers and active subscriptions that were active in the past 12 months (By Day for the past 365 days). The final dataset I am seeking would look something like this (365 Rows; 3 Columns):

```
Ref_Date     Subscribers        Subscriptions
6/1/2014        100              150
6/2/2014        101              153
…                 …               …
5/30/2015       106              160
5/31/2015       104              155
```

In addition, the value for "Ref_Date" in the above table would be "6/1/2014" for the query that is in this post. I would just like to do this for all 365 "Ref_Date"s with one data pull. 
Can anyone provide any assistance? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a table of dates and join it to the data. The example below uses a derived table from the same dataset to produce the list of dates.

Query:

```
SELECT Ref_date
    ,count(DISTINCT (user_id)) AS subscribers
    ,count(DISTINCT (subscription_id)) AS subscriptions
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT start_date AS ref_date
    FROM dataset
    WHERE start_date BETWEEN DATEADD(YYYY,-1,CURRENT_DATE) and CURRENT_DATE
    ) dateslist
INNER JOIN dataset ON start_date < DATEADD(YYYY, 1, ref_date)
    AND end_date >= ref_date
```

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ad3b26/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE dataset ( user_id, subscription_id, start_date, end_date, payment_amt ) AS
          SELECT  1,1, SYSDATE - 370, SYSDATE - 370 + INTERVAL '1' MONTH, 10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT  2,1, SYSDATE - 350, SYSDATE - 350 + INTERVAL '1' MONTH, 10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT  3,2, SYSDATE - 345, SYSDATE - 345 + INTERVAL '1' MONTH, 10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT  4,3, SYSDATE - 310, SYSDATE - 370 + INTERVAL '1' MONTH, 10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT  5,4, SYSDATE - 250, SYSDATE - 250 + INTERVAL '1' MONTH, 10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT  6,5, SYSDATE - 250, SYSDATE - 250 + INTERVAL '1' MONTH, 10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT  7,6, SYSDATE - 240, SYSDATE - 240 + INTERVAL '1' MONTH, 10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT  8,6, SYSDATE - 230, SYSDATE - 230 + INTERVAL '1' MONTH, 10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT  9,7, SYSDATE - 100, SYSDATE - 100 + INTERVAL '1' MONTH, 10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 10,8, SYSDATE -  50, SYSDATE -  50 + INTERVAL '1' MONTH, 10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 11,9, SYSDATE -  20, SYSDATE -  20 + INTERVAL '1' MONTH, 10 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 12,9, SYSDATE,       SYSDATE + INTERVAL '1' MONTH,       10 FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
WITH all_dates_of_year AS (
  SELECT TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' YEAR + LEVEL - 1 AS day
  FROM   DUAL
  CONNECT BY
         TRUNC(SYSDATE) - INTERVAL '1' YEAR + LEVEL - 1 <= TRUNC(SYSDATE)
)
SELECT day,
       COUNT( DISTINCT user_id ) AS num_users,
       COUNT( DISTINCT subscription_id ) AS num_subs
FROM   all_dates_of_year a
       LEFT OUTER JOIN
       dataset d
       ON ( a.day BETWEEN TRUNC( d.start_date ) AND TRUNC( d.end_date ) )
GROUP BY
       a.day
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ad3b26/1/0)**:

```
|                         DAY | NUM_USERS | NUM_SUBS |
|-----------------------------|-----------|----------|
|      June, 23 2014 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|      June, 24 2014 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|      June, 25 2014 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|      June, 26 2014 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|      June, 27 2014 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|      June, 28 2014 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|      June, 29 2014 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|      June, 30 2014 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|      July, 01 2014 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|      July, 02 2014 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|      July, 03 2014 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|      July, 04 2014 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|      July, 05 2014 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|      July, 06 2014 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|      July, 07 2014 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|      July, 08 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        1 |
|      July, 09 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        1 |
|      July, 10 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        1 |
|      July, 11 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        1 |
|      July, 12 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        1 |
|      July, 13 2014 00:00:00 |         3 |        2 |
|      July, 14 2014 00:00:00 |         3 |        2 |
|      July, 15 2014 00:00:00 |         3 |        2 |
|      July, 16 2014 00:00:00 |         3 |        2 |
|      July, 17 2014 00:00:00 |         3 |        2 |
|      July, 18 2014 00:00:00 |         3 |        2 |
|      July, 19 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        2 |
|      July, 20 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        2 |
|      July, 21 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        2 |
|      July, 22 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        2 |
|      July, 23 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        2 |
|      July, 24 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        2 |
|      July, 25 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        2 |
|      July, 26 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        2 |
|      July, 27 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        2 |
|      July, 28 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        2 |
|      July, 29 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        2 |
|      July, 30 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        2 |
|      July, 31 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        2 |
|    August, 01 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        2 |
|    August, 02 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        2 |
|    August, 03 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        2 |
|    August, 04 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        2 |
|    August, 05 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        2 |
|    August, 06 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        2 |
|    August, 07 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        2 |
|    August, 08 2014 00:00:00 |         2 |        2 |
|    August, 09 2014 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|    August, 10 2014 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|    August, 11 2014 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|    August, 12 2014 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|    August, 13 2014 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|    August, 14 2014 00:00:00 |         0 |        0 |
|    August, 15 2014 00:00:00 |         0 |        0 |
|    August, 16 2014 00:00:00 |         0 |        0 |
|    August, 17 2014 00:00:00 |         0 |        0 |
|    August, 18 2014 00:00:00 |         0 |        0 |
|    August, 19 2014 00:00:00 |         0 |        0 |
|    August, 20 2014 00:00:00 |         0 |        0 |

...

|      June, 21 2015 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|      June, 22 2015 00:00:00 |         1 |        1 |
|      June, 23 2015 00:00:00 |         2 |        1 |
```